# How to derive the equation to calculate height of stopper?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, friction, statics

I have a spherical ball of radius `r` places on an inclined plane of angle `θ`. What should be the minimum height of the stopper `h` so that the ball do not roll, if inclined plane is friction less. `m` depicted in the picture is the mass of the ball.

[image]

Comment: This is a statics problem - angular-momentum has nothing to do with this. And it is not really a question of friction either.

Comment: angular-momentum and friction would be valid if the surface is frictional ? I did not study newtonian-mechanics  after I left school. In my actual case I have a metal ball inside a pipe that will have to roll and overcome series of stoppers when the angle of inclination changes from 0 to 90 degrees

Comment: Your comment suggests that Qmechanics (who spends a lot of time tagging questions) got it wrong. This is not a homework question - but it was interpreted as one because of the way you phrased it. As phrased, it is a fairly simple college physics question. But, your real question - that of a ball traveling down a pipe with interior ridges - is actually a very difficult one to pose as a clear problem in Newtonian mechanics. You need to describe the real geometry correctly, and not try to over simplify. To be honest, I think you should ask https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please do have a shot at clarifying the question and the context. You have my interest. But, to get a good answer you have to explain what the real problem is - including that this is starting to sound like a problem in statistical dynamics. Models of ball bearings running down ridged ramps can be very complicated. I have down some work on rocks on conveyor belts, for example.

Comment: Yes, I put it in simple manner. Actually, I have a steel or copper pipe inside it is a metal ball of uniform density. when the pipe is parallel to the ground (0 degree )the ball can take any random position in the pipe as it is free to roll with slight deflection. so, I want to have ridges inside the pipe or circular fins of height h, inside that would restrict the free movement. Ball will roll to other end, when the pipe is inclined beyond certain +θ angle, ball falls back to original position when deflected to -θ.

Answer (score 1):

The way to calculate it is finding the height of the bump such that when the ball rolls over it the center of gravity goes *higher* than where it is now.

This way, the ball needs additional energy to go over the bump.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary stopper, there are 2 normal forces to balance the weight. One from the contact with the wedge and another from the contact with the stopper.

The limit case for the ball doesn't roll is when there is only the normal force due to the contact with the stopper. That is, when the first normal vanishes.